# DB2 in Oracle SQL Developer - Default Schema

Tags: schema, db2, oracle-sqldeveloper

When connecting to a DB2 database with Oracle SQL Developer, is there a way to specify my schema in the connection properties so that I'm always aimed where I want to be?

Comment: I know once connected, I can type 
    /*sqldev:stmt*/SET CURRENT SCHEMA= <schema>
and that will allow me to use the schema, but I'm looking to bypass that all together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how Oracle SQL Developer works, but at least the JDBC driver for DB2 has the option to specify the schema in the connection string, like:

```
jdbc:db2://server:50000/MYDB:currentSchema=MySchema;
```

If you can manually change the connection string that OSD is using, then perhaps you can add that option in.

Comment: Thanks! That's something I never thought of, and it seemed to work. For those wondering how this can be done in oracle while accessing a DB2 Database: 
you have 3 fields on the connection properties...
HostName:
Port:
Database:
In the database field, put the name followed by :currentSchema=SchemaName;
The string will look something like this... 
mydatabasename:currentSchema=myschemaname;

Cheers

Comment: I notice if the schema name matches your user name, you don't have to explicitly include the schema name with your SQL statement. I only say this because you can't always explicitly set the connection string (e.g. using Oracle SQL Developer to connect to DB2 database)